# Configurable tab-bar, or rich-featured terminal emulator

Tags: gnome-terminal, terminal-emulator, konsole

Is there any terminal emulator where the user can choose the position of the tab bar? I want to have the tab bar on the left, with vertically aligned tabs, or configure the tab-bar to be multi-line. I often have many (>20) tabs open in my terminal, and the information on the tabs becomes completely unreadable. I would like to configure the tab-bar to either be vertically aligned on the left, or be multi-row (a bit like the configurability of Tab Mix Plus in Firefox)

Can this be done in gnome-terminal, or in konsole, or in any other terminal emulator? Another feature I'm missing dearly is the 'monitor for silence' and 'monitor for activity' pair, with timeouts that can be configured. Also, I'd like the terminal to do pseudo-transparency like gnome-terminal can do in gnome. So in summary, I'm looking for a rich-featured terminal emulator.

Who can recommend one?

Related question:

- [Is there a (light-weight) replacement for `rxvt-unicode`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/821/is-there-a-light-weight-replacement-for-rxvt-unicode)

Comment: Are you using a feature-rich window manager? If so, you might be able to use a terminal emulator that doesn't have tabs, and let the window manager handle the tabbing.

Comment: I use Gnome at work and KDE at home. But do you mean that it might be possible to 'merge' multiple windows so that switching between them behaves like switching between tabs?

Comment: Have you considered something like `screen`?  I think both fluxbox and compiz can do window tabbing, but whether or not it is worth it to switch is up to you.

Comment: I'm already a fond screen user, but I would like to have a graphical overview of named tabs, preferably with the current directory or application in them; more or less like gnome-terminal is already doing, but then vertically on the left of the window.

Comment: You could configure `screen` to provide you with a list of currently open windows in your status bar.

Comment: @gerrit The positioning and sizing of windows, the ways to switch between them, and the decorations around them are entirely up to the window manager. So window managers can implement tabs. Only a few do; if you're interested, look at e.g. Sawfish or Awesome or Fluxbox (I don't know if any of these do support tabs the way you want them).

Comment: I combine konsole with screen: 5-6 "project" tabs, each with a screen session. This relieves cramped tab syndrome for me. I do not enable 'caption', but you could do that to get a list of tabs on each project.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend terminal emulator like urxvt, which has daemon-client version which allows opening new windows in instant, and many other features (but no tabs), and tiling window manager like i3 (the layout you want is called stacking, and most tiling WMs support it, in addition to tiling and tabbed).